# Anchor tags - equal height, still clickable with CSS?

Tags: css, height, anchor, equals

**I have a little code on jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/tYrCe/1/
Edit it if you like!

I have 3 buttons with anchor tags. I would like them to be equal in height.

**Requirements**

- Equal in height
- Independent of content (min-height, not ok)
- The whole link should still be clickable (javascript onclick, not ok)

Comment: Why is `min-height` not okay? The content can still expand beyond that minimum...and is JavaScript okay so long as it isn't used for the `onclick`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: table-cell`.

`table-layout: fixed` evenly distributes the available width between the cells.

Make sure the browser support is acceptable to you: http://caniuse.com/css-table
*(I assume no IE6/7 support is fine because you're using `outline`)*

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Ab6bg/

```
.urls {
    width: 300px;
    background: #fff;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed
}
.urls a {
    display: table-cell;
    outline: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The classic, pure CSS, way is to use a large bottom padding and then reverse margin as discussed in [this "Position is Everything" article](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight#how).

[**Here is your fiddle modified accordingly**](http://jsfiddle.net/tYrCe/4/).

HTML:

```
<div class="urls">
    <a href="#">A little content</a>
    <a href="#">A little more content with more text</a>
    <a href="#">A little very much more content with very much more text</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.urls {
    width: 300px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.urls a {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 30em;
    margin: 0 0 -29em;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

Comment: I'd completely forgotten about that. It's a good solution here.